# ¿Cómo cerrar un jframe con un jlabel sin que se cierren las otras ventanas?

Tags: java

Tengo varias ventanas y quiero cerrarlas con un label. 
El problema es que no he encontrado como cerrar alguna ventana sin que se cierren las demás.

El jframe principal esta con EXIT_ON_CLOSE  y los secundarios con DISPOSE.

```
private void jLabel12MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    //System.exit(0);
    dispose();
}
```

Comment: Prueba a quitar el `System.exit(0);`

Comment: excelente te agradezco, si era eso  lo también apareció en youtube